# Developing Xamarin no longer requires Visual Studio 2019 on win10？

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-mac

According to the document [Designing user interfaces with Xcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/), I am noted that

> Starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9, there will be no supported way to edit iOS storyboards on Windows. Use Visual Studio for Mac and the Xcode Interface Builder to continue building your Xamarin.iOS user interfaces.

We need to edit the storyboard on Xcode.

It told me that we can use `VS2019 for Mac` and `Xcode`. What I want to know is that can me develop the Xamarin using `VS2019` on Win10 any more, rather than installing VS2019 on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The background behind that notice is that Microsoft decided to not work on its iOS user interface visual designer any more (due to various reasons), so you lost the way to edit storyboard files on Windows.

So yes, you can continue to develop the Xamarin using VS2019 on Win10, but now that approach has many more restrictions.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/introduction?tabs=macos)

Answer (score 0):

Notice from Microsoft

> The iOS Designer was deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and
> Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.8, and removed in Visual Studio
> 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9. The
> recommended way to build iOS user interfaces is directly on a Mac
> running Xcode. For more information, see Designing user interfaces
> with Xcode.